# Can I use KafkaItemReader in Spring Batch to read from multiple topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-batch, kafka-topic

It's easy to use `KafkaItemReader` to read messages from one topic:

```java
return new KafkaItemReaderBuilder<String, Activity>()
    .consumerProperties(toProperties(of(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress,
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class,
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class
    )))
    .pollTimeout(ofMillis(600))
    .topic(checkOutTopicName)
    .build();
```

However, `topic` method only permits to assign a single topic. If I want to read `checkInTopicName` as well, I have create another bean for check in as well. The behavior of the job for check in is not that different from the one for check out and I think they should be more coherent.

Is there a way to read multiple topics with `KafkaItemReader`?

---

I feel that it might be an XY problem actually. In the next iteration I am going to use partitions `check-in-partition` and `check-out-partition` on a single topic instead of two separate topics. I think it will make my job more coherent, but for now I want to know how it could be done with two topics instead of partitions.

Comment: What if these topics contain different types of items? A reader should focus on a single data source (a single topic). If the duplicate bean definition is the problematic part, then you can create a single step-scoped bean where the topic is configurable with a job parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, since the Batch reader uses the assignment API of Kafka, therefore accepts a static list of TopicPartition instances, which get created with that single topic name.

The solution would be to use spring-kafka, not spring-batch , where you can read from a list of topics, including with a regex pattern.